# multiple jms connection factory

Tags: jms, spring-jms

i have two connection factories, one is for WAN(internet ip), another is for the LAN(lan ip), two connection factories are working fine now in my project. but the only thing is in some case of application deployment that LAN won't appear for the particular customer,but some are needed.then i need the application config will heardbeat the connection facotry what if the remote remote activeMQ server appear then connection, otherwise heardbeat it , but now sometimes the it will block/stuck the application starting procedure .(start processes will failed)

are there any way to resovled it ?

thanks .