# Tomcat 7 + JNDI Resource + IBM WebSphere MQ

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, ibm-mq, jndi

My mission is to connect Tomcat 7 to remote IBM MQ. I try create JNDI Resource in server.xml file but it doesn't work. I used example [from](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_do_I_connect_to_a_Websphere_MQ_.28MQ_Series.29_server_using_JMS_and_JNDI.3F).

Addinatinaly i added in this example **username** and **password**. But there is error when i call JNDI resource from java code.

```
<Resource
      name="jms/MyQCF"
      auth="Container"
      type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory"
      factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
      description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
      HOST="<mymqserver>"
      PORT="1414"
      CHAN="<mychannel>"
      TRAN="1"
      QMGR="<myqueuemanager>"/>
   <Resource
      name="jms/MyQ"
      auth="Container"
      type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
      factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
      description="JMS Queue for receiving messages from Dialog"
      QU="<myqueue>"/>
```

I've downloaded all required *.jars from [IBM sphere]/lib/java to Tomcat lib folder. Help me please, mb i'm doing somethink wrong. Maybe i need some IBM Client, but i don't know what is it.

*Edit:*
**The error stacktrace**

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceEnvFactory.getObjectInstan‌​ce(ResourceEnvFactor‌​y.java:117) 
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManag‌​er.java:321)
```

VERSION OF IBM MQ LIBS IS:

```
Implementation-Version: 7.0.1.8 - k701-108-120201
```

My current Resource in server.xml is:

```
<Resource
  name="jms/MyQCF"
  auth="Container"
  type="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
  factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactoryFactory"
  description="JMS Queue Connection Factory for sending messages"
  HOST="192.168.204.73"
  PORT="1415"
  username="***"
  password="***"
  CHAN="JAVA.CHANNEL"
  TRAN="1"
  QMGR="U.SEND"/>

<Resource
  name="jms/MyQ"
  auth="Container"
  type="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue"
  factory="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueFactory"
  description="JMS Queue for receiving messages from Dialog"
  QU="U.RECEIVE"/>
```

My java code:

```
System.out.println("servlet page*****************");

    Context ctx = null;
    try {
        ctx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
        System.out.println("ctx: " + ctx);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    QueueConnectionFactory qcf = null;
    try {
        qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/MyQCF");
        System.out.println("qcf: " + qcf);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My stacktrace:

servlet page*****************

ctx: org.apache.naming.NamingContext@463b1a3e

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceEnvFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceEnvFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:168)
    at kz.lalafa.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:45)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My Tomcat lib folder contains:

```
annotations-api.jar            
fscontext.jar
catalina-ant.jar               
geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec-1.0.1.jar
catalina-ha.jar                
geronimo-jms_1.1_spec-1.1.1.jar
catalina.jar                   
jasper-el.jar
catalina-tribes.jar            
jasper.jar
CL3Export.jar                  
jms.jar
CL3Nonexport.jar               
jndi.jar
com.ibm.mq.commonservices.jar  
jsp-api.jar
com.ibm.mq.defaultconfig.jar   
jta.jar
com.ibm.mqetclient.jar         
ldap.jar
com.ibm.mq.headers.jar         
providerutil.jar
com.ibm.mq.jar                 
rmm.jar
com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar            
servlet-api.jar
com.ibm.mqjms.jar              
tomcat-api.jar
com.ibm.mq.jms.Nojndi.jar      
tomcat-coyote.jar
com.ibm.mq.pcf.jar             
tomcat-dbcp.jar
com.ibm.mq.postcard.jar        
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
com.ibm.mq.soap.jar            
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
com.ibm.mq.tools.ras.jar       
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
connector.jar                  
tomcat-jdbc.jar
dhbcore.jar                    
tomcat-util.jar
ecj-4.2.2.jar                  
wmq.jmsra.rar
el-api.jar
```

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<web-app version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jms/MyQCF</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jms/MyQ</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.jms.Queue</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

Comment: What version of MQ client are the IBM MQ jars from?  Can you post the actual error you receive?

Comment: IBM WebSphere 7.

Comment: javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceEnvFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceEnvFactory.java:117) at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321) .............

Comment: You can click edit at under your question and add the error to the question this will let you format it and you can past the full stack trace.  Please provide a full MQ version, there was 7.0, 7.0.1, 7.1, 7.5, and each of them had many different fix packs, knowing the full version may be helpful if there was a defect that IBM fixed at that level.  On a Linux system you can find the version by running the following against one of the jar files: `unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version`

Comment: Please post the web.xml configuration, your code snippet and the complete stack trace.. thanks..

Comment: Is the myQCF and other resources declared in the descriptor web.xml?

Comment: still like to see resource configured and  sample/corresponding java code - using jdk10, tomee 7.x, ibmmq 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just decided to use Spring Boot for this - https://github.com/lzp4ever/IBM_WebSphere_MQ_Spring_Boot_JMS.

But i got new problem. My new problem at this link: [multiple jms connection factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19854396/multiple-jms-connection-factory)

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question you should probably put some more detail in as to how you used Spring Boot to solve the problem.  The part about the new problem if mentioned at all should be a comment to either your question or the answer but not part of the answer.

Comment: The question you link to was asked by a different user in 2013 and is related to ActiveMQ, are you sure that is the correct link?

Comment: this hithub link helped me to connect to IMB WebSphere. Tomcat itself is not bean container and it's hard to connect. With Spring boot it very simple.